# Type in script tag of HTML

Tags: html

In Html script tag, we add the type attribute.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"></script>
```

Is there another type of script that is used apart from JavaScript?

Comment: [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type attribute in script tag is used to tell the browser about MIME type or you can say media type. I have also never used different types but I have seen some types i.e.

- text/javascript
- text/ecmascript
- application/ecmascript
- application/javascript

By default, it is text/javascript.